# How to make Live Search including onload search

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql

I have a textarea which has some value, I need to search it at first(onload), then if I change the text written in textarea, I need to search new text (like google), when the textarea is empty, I need to get some message
Now I dont't get the result onload, when I try to edit my text I get result, but if i make textarea empty I get my table full

```
function searchValue() {
    $("#search").on("input",function(){
    $search = $("#search").val();
        if($search.length!=0){
            $.get('search.php',{"s":$search},function($data){
                $("#results").html($data);
            });
        }
    });
 }

<?php
            $connection = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "root", 'google');
            $connection->query ("SET NAMES 'utf8'");
            $query="SELECT * FROM `googleSearchResult` WHERE `info` LIKE '%$_GET[s]%'";
            $data=$connection->query($query);
            while ($result = $data->fetch_assoc()){
                echo "<br><p><a href='".$result['url']."'style='color:#1a0dab !important; font-size:20px'>".$result['title']."</a></p>";
                echo "<p style='color:#006621 !important; font-size:17px'>".$result['url']."</p>";
                echo "<p style='color:#545454 !important; font-size:16px'>".$result['info']."</p>"."<br>";
            }
            $connection->close();
            ?>

<input class="textarea2" id='search' type="text" value="someValue">
                    <p id='results'></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

maybe try adding a "keyup" method too

```
  $("#search").keyup(function(){
       var search=$(this).val();
       if(search!==''){
           $.get('search.php',{"s":$search},function($data){
            $("#results").html($data);
       }

   });
```